# 503 too many open connections error - did I muck something up?

Tags: apt, software-center, proxy, downloads, gpodder

**UPDATE UPDATE:** I think I did muck something up afterall. I think I set up a proxy because I'm in Mexico and wanted to use my account on Spotify. After doing some digging I ran the command: env | grep proxy I get :

```
http_proxy=http://5.9.70.75:8118/
socks_proxy=socks://65.184.87.89:30272/
https_proxy=https://199.200.120.36:8089/
```

Now I think if I just got rid of the proxy servers it might fix things.

**EARLIER POST:**

I'm not 100% sure if I mucked something up with my network connection options but I'm getting a lot of "503 too many open connection" errors when I try to do various things in Ubuntu. For example updates, downloads from software center, downloading podcasts from gpodder, etc.

Here's what I just got from running sudo apt-get upgrade:

```
39 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 14.8 kB/80.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 26.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main gcc-4.9-base amd64 4.9.1-0ubuntu1
503  Too many open connections
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gccgo-4.9/gcc-4.9-base_4.9.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  503  Too many open connections
```

Answer (score 1):

No its not a problem on your side....

I believe what is happening is that the archive http:// site has too many connections open.  From what I recall in a similar situation, another mirror site would be selected to try to complete the download depending on settings.

Comment: Dont think its an issue with mirror sites. I've tried several different ones through 'Software and Updates.' But I did get another clue. I use [grive](https://github.com/Grive/grive) for syncing folders with google drive. When I just ran it from the terminal I saw this line: 

`[gr::http::CurlErrMsgTag*] = Received HTTP code 503 from proxy after CONNECT`

Makes me thin I set up my connection through a proxy but I cant figure out where I would set this.